# Modifying "value" attribute of "text" input not working using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textbox

I have a question regarding a text input field, whose value is modified by a JavaScript function. Here is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script>
            function runScript()
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Changing Text Input Value to Name 2";
                document.getElementById("name_input0").value = "Name 2";
                document.getElementById("name_hidden0").value = "Name 2";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="hidden" id="name_hidden0" value="Name 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name_enter0" id="name_input0" value="Name 1"/>
    <input type="button" value="Run Script" onClick="runScript()"/>
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, the text and hidden input are both populated with the value "Name 1". When I click the button, the page looks like this:

[image: Page View After Running JavaScript]

which makes perfect sense, however, if I look at the source code using the Developer Tools (I tried Firefox and Chrome) and look at the HTML code, I see the following:

[image: Underlying HTML after Running JavaScript]

Why did the "value" attribute of the text input field not change in the underlying HTML, but the hidden input "value" did?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For text inputs:

The HTML `value` attribute sets the *default* value.

The DOM `value` property holds the *current* value.

There isn't a 1:1 mapping between them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! How would I change the "default" value using JavaScript?

Comment: You can use setAttribute, but why would you want to?

Comment: in my actual application, I have another button that adds more text boxes, by appending to the current HTML, and I would like to keep track of what has been entered/modified in the current text boxes.